# sed command in a Jenkins declarative pipeline script

Tags: sed, jenkins-pipeline

I want to insert multiple lines into a file. When is do this on a Linux system using:

```
sed -i "/repositories {/amaven {\n\t\turl 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2';\n\t}" test
```

it works fine but fails on Jenkins declarative pipeline with error

```
+ sed -i /repositories {/amaven {
        url http://repo1.maven.org/maven2;
    } test
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown command: `u'
```

Answer (score 0):

This got this resolved using '''.

'''sed -i \"/repositories {/amaven {\nurl \'http:\/\/repo1.maven.org\/maven2\';\n}" test'''